# Form for updating model info is blank

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to provide a form to update user info such as employment, location, birthday, interests. The form I tried to make will not show any of this info however, it just shows a submit button.

```
    user_info = models.UserInfo.objects.get(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = UserChangeForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)
         if form.is_valid():
             form.save()
             return redirect('login:login_view')

    else:

            form = UserChangeForm(instance=request.user)
            context = { 'user_info' : user_info,
                    'form ' : form }
            return render(request, 'account.djhtml',context)
```

I'm pretty sure I need to use user_info but Im not to sure how to do that. If anyone can point me in the right direction i'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks

```
  <form method="post"action="{% url 'social:account_view' %}">
                     {% csrf_token %}
                     {{ form.as_p }}

                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </form>
```

The djhtml I tried

Comment: Where is the get method?

Comment: `instance=request.user` I assume you meant `instance=user_info` both times.